# как при save() обновить существующие записи в базе данных yii2

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Есть массив данные из которого извлекаются через цикл, а затем данные подставляются в поля модели для их сохранения и валидации:

```
       if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '') && !$model->validate()) {
        foreach ($text as $id => $newsText) {
            $model = new ThisDay;
            $news = News::findNews($id);
            $model->news_name = $newsText;
            $model->old_name = $news->name;
            $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
            $model->id_news = $id;
            $model->editor_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
            $model->id_region = REGION_ID;
            $model->cdate = $datePub;
            $model->date = $datePub;
            $model->validate();
            $model->save();
        }
    }
```

В `$text` я получаю массив вида `array(1) { [612539]=> string(44) "Где в Приморье после бла бла бла" }` в цикле я извлекаю из него id новости (612539) например и текст статьи. С формы я получаю измененный заголовок статьи, как в примере выше, и по id ищу в другой таблице прежний заголовок. При сохранении в первый раз сохраняется оба имени, но при повторной попытке сделать save() этой записи данные в таблице не меняются.

Вопрос: каким образом я могу изменять данные в `$model->news_name = $newsText;` при save() записи?

Comment: Код у вас запутанный. Как я понимаю, каждый раз создается новая запись в таблице, и не кого обновление записей у вас нет. Странно что  при вызове методов `validate` и `save` в цикле вы не обрабатываете ошибки.

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов как раз из за условия и обрабатываю) код срабатывает тогда, когда форма не валидная) А как нужно переделать код чтобы он обновлял записи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу создав функцию поиска по модели по id новости. Если есть - переписываются новые данные. Так выглядит новая функция

```
public function actionUpdate($id, $newsText, $editorId, $timeUp) {
    $model = ThisDay::findOne(['id_news' => $id]);
    $model->news_name = $newsText;
    $model->editor_id = $editorId;
    $model->cdate = $timeUp;
    $model->save();
    return $model;
}
```

Вставил ее в конец условия функции actionList, вот так:

```
public function validateEdit() {
    $editNames = $this->editItems();
    $datePub = Date::now();
    foreach ($editNames as $key => $text) {
        $model = new ThisDay;
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '') && !$model->validate()) {
            foreach ($text as $id => $newsText) {
                $model = new ThisDay;
                $news = News::findNews($id);
                $model->news_name = $newsText;
                $model->old_name = $news->name;
                $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
                $model->id_news = $id;
                $model->editor_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
                $model->id_region = REGION_ID;
                $model->cdate = $datePub;
                $model->date = $datePub;
                $model->validate();
                $model->save();
//сохраняет новые данные в модель, если запись уже есть в таблице
                $updateModel = $this->actionUpdate($id, $newsText, Yii::$app->user->id, $datePub);
            }
        }
    }
    return $model;
}
```

Вроде работает как нужно - новые сохраняет, а старые перезаписывает